# A problem on irreduciblity of $P(x)^2+c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

So I was wondering over this as we know $x^2+1$ is not reducible over $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. But isnt it quite suprising as soon as $x=2y^2$ it becomes factorizable $4y^4+1=(2y^2+1)^2-4y^2=(2y^2+2y+1)(2y^2-2y+1)$ , so the question is find all non constant polynomials $P(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $P(x)^2+c$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ where $c \in \mathbb{Z}$ and hopefully generalize to $P(x)^n+c$ it would for example be interesting to find such for $x^2-2$ or $x^3+2$.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting exploration, but possibly too broad for a single question on this site.  Is there something specific you'd like more information about on this topic?

Comment: @abiessu ya maybe i was too broad , to start things off i just want to solve this for $P(x)^2+c$ .

Comment: Is the problem to find for *each fixed* $c \in \Bbb Z$ all the polynomials $P(x)$ such that $P(x)^2 + c$ is reducible? N.b. for any $k \in \Bbb Z$ the polynomial $P(x)^n - k^n$ is reducible for all $P$ with $\deg P \geq 1$.

Comment: @TravisWillse yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about **all**, but here's one $3$-parameter family of solutions.

$$ \left(x^2 + (h + 2 k) x + (a - hk - 4 k^2)\right)^2 +
k^2 (4 a - h^2 - 8 h k - 16 k^2) = \left(x^2 + h x + a - 2 h k - 4 k^2\right)
\left(x^2 + (h + 4 k) x + a\right) $$